# Where is the last bracket gone in this expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex which is matching the word with my array, but it is not showing the last bracket with them. My JS Code

```
function decodeEntities(s){
    var str, temp= document.createElement('p');
    temp.innerHTML= s;
    str= temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
    temp=null;
    return str;
}
 var code = ["<span>","<div>","<pre>","<spat>"];

    var string = code.join(", ");
   var string_to_pass="<span";
   var re =  new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)" + decodeEntities(string_to_pass) + "(\\w+)(?!\\w)", "g"), match, matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(string)) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

I saw a array with two matches in the console without the last close bracket.

```
Array [ "<span", " <spat" ]
```

How can i stop this script from removing last bracket `>`. Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps because you haven't included a closing bracket in `string_to_pass`? I don't see one in the rest of your regex either so why would you expect one to be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
var re =  new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)" + decodeEntities(string_to_pass) + "(\\w+\\W)", "g"), match, matches = [];
```

Comment: or `"(?:^|\\W)" + decodeEntities(string_to_pass) + "(\\W|$)"`

Comment: It worked, really thanks for helping me. Will accept this answer as correct in just 10 minutes